# Getting rid of Twitter Bootstrap thumbnail border

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, border

I'm trying to get rid of the default thumbnail thin grey border in Twitter Bootstrap.

I can target the borders, for example if I use:

```
.thumbnails > li { border:1px solid red; }
```

all the thumbnail borders change to red.

But if I use:

```
.thumbnails > li { border:0; }
```

it still leaves the borders with a thin grey line. I cannot get rid of that. I've tried to change the color to white (my background is white, so it could be a solution) but it doesn't work.

How can I get rid of that thin grey border?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thumbnail borders are applied to the `.thumbnail` element, inside the `<li>`. Anyway, the "extra" thin line you talk about could be the `box-shadow` applied to that class.

So you can try:

```
.thumbnail {
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem but neither setting the border or the box-shadow to 0 worked for me. I was finally able to remove the border by setting the background of the thumbnail class to transparent.

Like this:

```
.thumbnail{
  background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my version of BootStrap, it was this:

```
img.wp-post-image {

    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

set them both to 0, and it worked:

```
img.wp-post-image {

    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the method advised by @albertedevigo doesn't work then **try changing the class from 'img-thumbnail' to 'img-responsive'**.

The .img-responsive class applies display: block; and max-width: 100%; and height: auto; to the image.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row no-pad">
          <div class="col-md-2"><img src="E:\VIPUL\Adobe Lightroom\Modified\Awesome.jpg" 
class="img-responsive"  alt="Awesome.jpg">
        </div>
       </div>
```

**CSS**

```
     .row.no-pad.img-responsive{
      margin-right:0px;
      margin-left:0px;
      border:none;
    }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**Don't Panic :)**

**Simply copy and paste this to your style.css**

```
.thumbnail {
    display: contents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the get rid of it ! Holaa

```css
.img-responsive {
 width:100%;
 border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 3.3.6 it can be found in the bootstrap.css file

```
.thumbnail{
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background-color: #74003;
  **border: 1px solid #ddd;** 
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
 }
```